# What is an RPC Callback Thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2008

I am using Visual Studio 2008.  The Threads window shows two RPC Callback Threads for my application.  What are these?  More specifically, are they suppose to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are Remote Procedure Call Threads: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call

Here is an msdn article on how Remote Procedure Call works on windows: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373935%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

The articles only deal with RPC over a network, but it is also used for inter-process communication.

Comment: RPC is used for inter-process/machine communication by quite a few services (e.g. LSA and SAM).

Answer (score 2):

In Windows, RPC is most commonly used by COM+ (DCOM). Considering that you didn't use RPC intentionally, COM appears to be the most likely cause.