# Visual Studio 2010 Unknown Threads in COM Project

Tags: multithreading, visual-studio-2010, com, visual-studio-debugging

I have two COM projects that I built in VS-2010 and in the Debugger I can see some extra threads. Can someone tell me what Win32 Thread and RPC Callback Thread mean and where I can find information about their details. I attached some pictures from the Threads window where you can see the Call Stack, too.

[image: Unknown Threads in Apartment Threading project]

[image: Unknown Threads in Free Threading project]

Comment: Tools > Options > Debugging > Symbols => tick the Microsoft Symbol Server option so you get debug info for operating system DLLs.  Seeing thread-pool threads being used in a program that uses COM or runs on Win10 is entirely normal.

Comment: Thanks, this will be enough to start studying the topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Hans Passant's suggestion, these threads would be related to the Windows. Like the RPC Callback Thread in your screen shot, my understanding it was used for the inter-process communication especially for COM+ (DCOM).

Reference:
[What is an RPC Callback Thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5225635/what-is-an-rpc-callback-thread)